# How to handle 3 or more clients in telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

i want to use 3 or more telegram clients at the same time, with 1 or/and 2 clients i don't have problems, but with 3 clients i get errors.

```
    client2 = TelegramClient('session1', api_id2, api_hash2)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 294, in __init__
    session.set_dc(
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 168, in set_dc
    self._update_session_table()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 194, in _update_session_table
    c.execute('delete from sessions')
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

What i want to do:

I want to use multiple accounts, one will only stay in groups, and when someone join in the group, the first account will get event "event.user_joined" and get the member id and then, using others account send them a private message (I already realized this part, but only with 2 accounts) but i want, for every 50 messages sent, to switch to next account. In this case, first 50 messages to be sent by "client1", next 50 messages to be sent by "client2" until last client i have (I want atleast 6) and then start again.

This is the code im using now

```
    @client.on(events.ChatAction)
    async def handler(event):
        index = 0
        if (event.user_added or event.user_joined):
            user = await event.get_user()
            receiver = InputPeerUser(user.id,user.access_hash)
            index = 0
            try:  
                if index < 50:
                    await client1.send_message(receiver, message)
                    print('Message sent successfully!') 
                elif index < 100:
                    await client2.send_message(receiver, message)
                    print('Message sent successfully!') 
                elif index < 150:
                    await client3.send_message(receiver, message)
                    print('Message sent successfully!') 
                # elif index < 200:
                    # await client4.send_message(receiver, message)
                    # print('Message sent successfully!') 
                # elif index < 250:
                    # await client5.send_message(receiver, message)
                    # print('Message sent successfully!') 
                elif index < 200:
                    index == 0
                
            except:
                pass
```

i used this part of code for logging in more than 2 clients.

```
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
client1 = TelegramClient('session1', api_id1, api_hash1)
client1.start()
client2 = TelegramClient('session1', api_id2, api_hash2)
client2.start()
client3 = TelegramClient('session1', api_id3, api_hash3)
client3.start()
client4 = TelegramClient('session1', api_id4, api_hash4)
client4.start()
client5 = TelegramClient('session1', api_id5, api_hash5)
client5.start()
```

And this is the error i get, when im trying to connect the 3rd client

```
PS C:\Users\37378\Desktop\Telegram new member dm> python .\main.py
Please enter your phone (or bot token): 6282274692947
Please enter the code you received: 30365
Signed in successfully as Dufufj Ff
Please enter your phone (or bot token): 6281996803497
Please enter the code you received: 63977
Signed in successfully as Hduduf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\37378\Desktop\Telegram new member dm\main.py", line 31, in <module>
    client2.start()
  File "C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 134, in start
    else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 141, in _start
    await self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 537, in connect
    self.session.auth_key = self._sender.auth_key
  File "C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 180, in auth_key
    self._update_session_table()
  File "C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\sessions\sqlite.py", line 194, in _update_session_table
    c.execute('delete from sessions')
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-47' coro=<Connection._send_loop() running at C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:311> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-48' coro=<Connection._recv_loop() running at C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\network\connection\connection.py:329> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-49' coro=<MTProtoSender._send_loop() running at C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:462> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-50' coro=<MTProtoSender._recv_loop() running at C:\Users\37378\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py:505> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `telethon` library is an asynchronous library so which means, each task is handled asynchronously.

To answer your code, it is important each of those clients is created in its own loop so use this;

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash, loop=loop)
client.start()
```

Hope this helps